# Why is measuring $C_v$ much more difficult than measuring $C_p$ for gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

It is intuitively the other way around. To measure $C_v$, one just need to seal the gas in some rigid container. To measure $C_p$, one need to allow the gas expand, which seems likely to incur error.

Comment: Where did you find the statement that measuring $C_v$ is much more difficult?

Comment: it depends on the regime you are using. imagine the pressures and vessels you would need if you were to test liquid or near liquid $H_2O$. To measure at constant pressures you need a piston-like contraption that works against some some constant force, not likely to crush your equipment and can be in done small steps but how would you make an adjustable size vessel that is always known size and can survive the pressures you don't know yet but will encounter.

Comment: @valerio92  The book by Sackur, LEHRBUCH DER THERMOCHEMIE UND THERMODYNAMIK. It is in German.

Comment: The very first thing to ask yourself is *'What precision do I desire?'*. For the purposes of a teaching lab, two significant figure would be pretty good and three would be great. It's actually easier to obtain that level of precision for constant volume (just stick it in a closed steel vessel). On the other hand if you are compiling technical tables for wide distribution you'd like a *minimum* of five significant figures, and that adds complexity to both measurements but it adds much more to the constant volume measurement.